# Find first ancestor commit in another branch

Tags: git

I want to find the most recent commit that's included in another branch; given the history

```
A-B-C---E  <-master
  └-F---G  <-develop
    └-H-I  <-branch1
```

I want to find F. Note that I only know the starting point branch1, and not the names of the other branches.

I know that I can simply check for the lowest i≥0 so that

```
git branch --contains branch1~i
```

outputs more than one line, but that seems wasteful.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're looking for. You want to find earliest (or most recent; I don't know if "first" means "first in history" or "nearest to where I am") commit that is included in a branch different than the current one? That is contained within the current one as well as another branch? Your diagram does not actually show any branches (I'm assuming that E, G, and I are commits), so I can't tell which of those you are counting.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Added and clarified; the diagram was indeed way too imprecise.

Comment: Well, what you're wanting is `git merge-base branch1 develop`, but I don't know of any (easy) way to do that if you don't know what your branch was spawned from, without doing a `merge-base` against every other branch and then somehow picking the "winner"...

Comment: @phihag I guess I'm still left wondering why you are trying to do this. What is your eventual goal? Also, in your original diagram, you had `HEAD` on what is now labelled `branch1`, but you said you were looking for `F` or `H`; I'm unclear how `H` would be considered to be on another branch, as it's only on `branch1`. It might help me understand if you describe your eventual goal.

Comment: I see you've edited again, but you still say "other branches" without specifying "other" in comparison to which branch. Do you mean in comparison to `branch1`? As in, you are trying to find the most recent commit for which `branch1` is not the only reference to that commit?

Comment: @BrianCampbell Clarified the language again. I want to generate a log of all changed entries in a gitolite [VREF hook](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html), where I get the old and new sha1 of a branch. Unfortunately, when a new branch is created, I only get the latest sha1, but still want to generate a list of all the new commits. Yes, I'm trying to find the most recent commit for which `branch1` is not the only reference (from a branch).

Comment: @phihag Thanks, that clarifies what you were looking for. Hopefully my answer should be what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, take a look at the [post-receive-email](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email#L277) script that comes with your Git distribution (should be installed somewhere like `/usr/share/doc/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email` if you want a local copy). This has a long comment that describes how to find only commits that are new in a given branch, and haven't been seen in any others before:

```
    # Consider this:
    #   1 --- 2 --- O --- X --- 3 --- 4 --- N
    #
    # O is $oldrev for $refname
    # N is $newrev for $refname
    # X is a revision pointed to by some other ref, for which we may
    #   assume that an email has already been generated.
    # In this case we want to issue an email containing only revisions
    # 3, 4, and N.  Given (almost) by
    #
    #  git rev-list N ^O --not --all
    #
    # The reason for the "almost", is that the "--not --all" will take
    # precedence over the "N", and effectively will translate to
    #
    #  git rev-list N ^O ^X ^N
    #
    # So, we need to build up the list more carefully.  git rev-parse
    # will generate a list of revs that may be fed into git rev-list.
    # We can get it to make the "--not --all" part and then filter out
    # the "^N" with:
    #
    #  git rev-parse --not --all | grep -v N
    #
    # Then, using the --stdin switch to git rev-list we have effectively
    # manufactured
    #
    #  git rev-list N ^O ^X
```

There are more details to handle corner cases in the comment, and the rest of the script; but if the basic case is all you care about, this should give you the answer:

```
git rev-parse --not --all | grep -v I | git rev-list --stdin I
```

where you can calculate `I` as `$(git rev-parse branch1)`. The last entry of the result will be the commit `H`, you can reach the most recent ancestor in *another* branch with `H^` then.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the branch with H-I, for example branch1

`git reflog show --all|grep branch1`

The highest number in accolades is your first commit on that branch.

Comment: Well, this definitely works, but feels even hackier than iterating *i*. For one, the reflog shouldn't be needed to answer the question. Additionally, the `I` commit may not actually be in any branch, or be in multiple branches. And one should really grep for `refs/heads/branch1@` lest `my_branch11` is matched as well.